# serial port communication in Android11

Tags: io

`Using serial port communication in Android, the data format of the sender is ASCII, but when I use Java to receive the data from BufferedInputStream, it is garbled. Why?

Android11

Baud rate and other settings are one-to-one correspondence accurate
Baud rate 9600 Stop bit 1 Data bit 8 Parity bit NONE Flow control is NONE

For example
When the sending format is ASCII, the sending data is 123, but the data I read from mBuffInputStream is 103, -10, -10, 108, 25, 0;
But the theoretical value should be 49, 50, 51, 0;

```
`    @Override//每隔 100 毫秒会触发一次run
    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
        try {
            int available = mBuffInputStream.available();
            if (available == 0) return;
            byte[] received = new byte[1024];
            int size = mBuffInputStream.read(received);

            if (size > 0 && serialInter != null) {
                byte[] data = Arrays.copyOf(received, size);
                serialInter.readData(path, data, size);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "串口读取数据异常:" + e.toString());
        }
    }`
```

Here is my receiving code

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. The hardware interface is RS232 level but my line is TTL type.